# Most performant way to test if one vector is permutation of another

Tags: r

My current solution to test if one vector contains the same values than another irrespective of the order is

```
test_perm <- function(a, b) identical(sort(a), sort(b))
test_perm(1:4, 4:1) # TRUE
test_perm(1:4, 1:4) # TRUE
test_perm(1:4, 1:5) # FALSE
test_perm(4:1, 4:1) # TRUE
```

It feels a bit wrong to be forced to sort `a` and `b` first, so I was wondering what the canonical way would be, i.e. what is the recommended way of doing that in `R`, if I am mostly concerned about speed?

(Small update thanks to the comment from @sindri)

Comment: The requierement are a bit unclear. Shouldn't `test_perm(4:1, 4:1)` return TRUE? Are you not looking for `setequal()`?

Comment: Yes, it should return `TRUE` (I forgot the `sort` on `a` - THX). A permutation contains exactly the same elements but in a different order. `setequal` would fail for this case `setequal(c(1,1), 1)` returns `TRUE` but should return `FALSE` because `a` contains more elements then `b.`

Comment: Since `sort` is a built-in, it is likely to be optimal from a performant point of view. Short of something using `rcpp` you are unlikely to do better than you currently are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two strategies, with benchmarking data provided by the `benchmark()` function in the `rbenchmark` package.

```
# Your strategy using identical(). Note that I sort a and b in case a is not ordered.
set.seed(123)
a <- sample(1:1000, 100, replace = FALSE)
b <- sample(1:1000, 100, replace = FALSE)
identical(sort(a), sort(b))
> FALSE

# using anti_join() from dplyr. Anti-join returns the rows in a that are not in b.
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)
a <- sample(1:1000, 100, replace = FALSE)
b <- sample(1:1000, 100, replace = FALSE)
diff <- anti_join(data.frame(a), data.frame(b), by = c("a" = "b"))
nrow(diff) == 0  # if all rows in a are in b, diff should have zero rows
> FALSE
```

Now here is the benchmarking data:

```
library(rbenchmark)
set.seed(123)
a <- sample(1:1000, 100)
b <- sample(1:1000, 100)

benchmark( 
  "sort_identical" = {
    identical(sort(a), sort(b))
  },
  "anti_join" = {
    require(dplyr)
    diff <- anti_join(data.frame(a), data.frame(b), by = c("a" = "b"))
    nrow(diff) == 0
  },
  replications = 1000,
  columns = c("test", "replications", "elapsed",
          "relative", "user.self", "sys.self")
  )

            test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
2      anti_join         1000    2.47   22.455      2.41        0
1 sort_identical         1000    0.11    1.000      0.11        0
```

The actual benchmarking data will depend on your system resources, but your approach of using `identical()` after sorting is very fast in comparison to my other idea of `anti_join()`. Hopefully you can also takeaway from this answer that you can test the speed of code yourself. I happen to like the `rbenchmark` package, but the `microbenchmark` package is nice, too.

We can expect `sort()` to perform really well since it is a generic base R function. However, if you read the help file for sort, you find that it actually uses the internal generic primitive function `xtfrm()` to sort numeric data. If you can guarantee your data will be numeric you can get a speed boost by calling `xtfrm()` directly. `xtfrm()` may be slower with other types of data.

```
set.seed(123)
a <- sample(1:1000, 100)
b <- sample(1:1000, 100)

benchmark( 
  "sort" = {
    identical(sort(a), sort(b))
  },
  "xtfrm" = {
    identical(xtfrm(a), xtfrm(b))
  },
  replications = 1000,
  columns = c("test", "replications", "elapsed",
              "relative", "user.self", "sys.self")
  )

   test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
1  sort         1000    0.11       11      0.10        0
2 xtfrm         1000    0.01        1      0.01        0
```

Comment: Thanks for the benchmark. Yes, I know the benchmarking libraries (`bench` is another one). I was just wondering whether there is maybe a dedicated function in base `R` which I am simply not aware of. For me the task seems to be very common and hence I thought there is a canonical way of doing it. +1 for the nice idea of `anti_join` (an idea which I never would have had, so alone for that it was worth  posting the question ;)